# Pyusb/libusb0 insufficient permissions Windows

Tags: python, windows, usb, libusb, pyusb

I want to read out a USB measurement device in python. For this I use the usbtmc module. It requires Pyusb and libusb-win32. I installed both and it seems that they are running fine. In the device manager I can find my USB device. And in python too. For example:

```
import usbtmc
dev = usbtmc.list_devices()
print(dev)
```

It returns the right device.

But when I want to connect to it:

```
instr =  usbtmc.Instrument(2391, 11288)
print(instr.ask("*IDN?"))
```

I get following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\Elektroniklabor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb10.py", line 403, in _check
raise USBError(_str_error[ret], ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you run the script as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, I started the cmd in admin mode and start with it my python script with the code above. Is there any 'driver permission' option in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Keysight support helped me out: I had to install the Keysight drivers (connection expert) and the pyvisa and pyvisa-py module. It is now working!